# Mobile website. viewport width gets stuck going back to portrait

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a mobile website and so far it looks great in portrait, and when i turn to landscpape and it adjusts and looks fine as well.
as soon as I go BACK to portrait, the width stays the same as it was in landscape, and the layout gets jacked. These are the meta tags that i have on the top of my page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" />
```

also, my css widths are based on percentages, and the body wrapper is set to width 100%.

Can anyone at least point me in the right direction here. Do I need some fancy javascript or css media query ? i will provide code if needed.
Also, it behaves inconsistently on different devices. This is happening mostly on Android...

Thanks for any help !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is defining width in the viewport meta tag. When width is set to `device-width`, the available width will always be the portrait width of the device regardless of orientation. It's seems confusing, but `device-width` doesn't mean "current available horizontal area", but rather the literally standard screen width of the device.

When width is not specified, Mobile Safari actually assigns `device-height` as the width in landscape orientation. Again, that may sound counter-intuitive, but we're talking about standard spec width and height in normal, portrait orientation.

Android phones may or may not display a similar behavior. I've been unable to find any confirmation one way or another. However, unfortunately, the width must be specified as device-width on Android to make it work at all.

As a result, your best bet is probably going to be shoring up the behavior with media queries. You can detect the orientation and width of the device and apply styles based on that. For example:

```
@media all and (device-width: 320) and (orientation: portrait) { ... }
@media all and (device-width: 480) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks for the very helpful info ! i am going to try it tonight and let you know how it worked :)